# Maven Clean Fails with Signature Exception

Tags: java, maven

Trying to run a maven build on my system, the first step fails with `java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SHA256withRSA Signature not available`

Here's the full error, I guess something with the certificates or the security config in my local java installation is wrong, any hints are appreciated:

`mvn clean -X`

```
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T08:41:47-08:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec
Java version: 1.8.0, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.11.6", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
[DEBUG] Created new class realm maven.api
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm maven.api
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.enterprise.inject.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.enterprise.util.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.inject.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.classrealm < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.cli < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.exception < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution.scope < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.model < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.monitor < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.plugin < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.profiles < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.project < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.reporting < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.rtinfo < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.settings < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.toolchain < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.usability < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authentication < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.events < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.observers < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.proxy < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.resource < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.component < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.container < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.context < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.logging < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.personality < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParser < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlSerializer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.collection < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.deployment < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.graph < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.impl < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.installation < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.metadata < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.resolution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.spi < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.transfer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.version < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.helpers.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.spi.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG] Populating class realm maven.api
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec/conf/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from /Users/Ben/.m2/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading global toolchains from /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.3.9/libexec/conf/toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user toolchains from /Users/Ben/.m2/toolchains.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at /Users/Ben/.m2/repository
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for /Users/Ben/.m2/repository
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project MyProject:MyProject:jar:0.0.1: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging jar from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] === REACTOR BUILD PLAN ================================================
[DEBUG] Project: MyProject:MyProject:jar:0.0.1
[DEBUG] Tasks:   [clean]
[DEBUG] Style:   Regular
[DEBUG] =======================================================================
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building MyProject 0.0.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
[DEBUG] Using transporter WagonTransporter with priority -1.0 for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
[DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file /Users/Ben/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom.lastUpdated
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.972 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-09-27T20:46:02-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/286M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed: SHA256withRSA Signature not available -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getPluginDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:179)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:284)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:241)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecution(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.setupMojoExecutions(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:131)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan(DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.BuilderCommon.resolveBuildPlan(BuilderCommon.java:96)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:109)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:282)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:287)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:103)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:267)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed(ArtifactTransportListener.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:581)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:1066)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter$GetTaskRunner.run(WagonTransporter.java:560)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.execute(WagonTransporter.java:427)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.get(WagonTransporter.java:404)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:350)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1917)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:301)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:295)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1369)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:156)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:925)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:860)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1043)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1371)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1355)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:275)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:254)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:318)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:363)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:219)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.execute(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:832)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:983)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:352)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:260)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1351)
    ... 66 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:129)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:215)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:143)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:79)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:347)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SHA256withRSA Signature not available
    at java.security.Signature.getInstance(Signature.java:224)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.verify(X509CertImpl.java:434)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.verifySignature(BasicChecker.java:166)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.check(BasicChecker.java:147)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:119)
    ... 77 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

Comment: it can be corrupted. Try to remove maven-clean-plugin form your local repository, it will cause maven to download plugin jar again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what was causing this:

I was using powermock, mockito and had to add this line in the java.security configuration:

```
security.provider.2=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
```

to:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/java.security
```

Now I guess that was the reason the signature could not be generated, because it was using the bouncy castle implementation of the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ instead of https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/ in your settings.xml. 
Therefore, your maven plugin will avoid some problems with SSL connectivity.

On the other hands, please check the configuration for SSL in MAC OS if you keep using https.